# uncheck a list of checkboxes with a button in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxs,and a button "Validate",what I want is when I click on that button all the checkBoxes will be unchecked

I work with angularJS,this is my code:

```
<table>
<tbody ng-model="finalOperationsList">
  <tr ng-repeat="item in finalOperationsList track by $index ">
     <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="$scope.selectedAll" checkbox-group /></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<div class="col-sm-3">
  <button ng-click="duplicateFichePaquets(eclatementCourante.ordreFabricationId)">Validate</button>
</div>
```

and this is the js:

```
 $scope.duplicateFichePaquets = function(ordreFabricationId) {

                     $http
                            .get(URL)
                            .success(
                                   function(gammeof) {
                         $scope.finalOperationsList =gammeof.operationsList;
                                      $scope.selectedAll = false;
                                   });
                         }
```

I use a directive to send the id of each checked element when I click on an other button,this is the directive:

```
.directive("checkboxGroup", function() {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                // Determine initial checked boxes
                if (scope.array.indexOf(scope.item.id) !== -1) {
                    elem[0].checked = true;
                }

                // Update array on click
                elem.bind('click', function() {
                    var index = scope.array.indexOf(scope.item.id);
                    // Add if checked
                    if (elem[0].checked) {
                        if (index === -1) scope.array.push(scope.item.id);
                    }
                    // Remove if unchecked
                    else {
                        if (index !== -1) scope.array.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                    // Sort and update DOM display
                    scope.$apply(scope.array.sort(function(a, b) {
                        return a - b
                    }));
                });
            }
        }
    })
```

but what I get as a result,when I click on that button "Validate" I get nothing,the ckeckboxes will not be unchecked
any help please
thanks for help
Update:
when I remove the directive from the checkbox it works,but I think the problem is with it :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VSph2/283/

Comment: thanks Sir for your reply,I did a try like your example without using the directive "checkbox-group" it works but I want this works with this directive :(